# PowerBI: Last 3 Non Blank Values from column

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table where I get the status of the employees tasks day by day.

As in below image I get the values(Confidential, so just entered dummy data).

[image]

Then I did unpivoted the dates column and made a copy of that and split with space so that I can get the date value.

[image]

Here I would like to show the last 3 commented values in a table visualization for each task.

Like as in above image, if the 5/31/2017 value is not available, then it should get the values of 5/29/2017 plan, 5/29/2017 actual, 5/30/2017 plan values i.e nothing but the last 3 non blank values.

Any suggestions please.

Mohan V

Comment: Have you checked [`TOPN`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492198.aspx) dax function?

Comment: @user5226582 Not actually. I am just new to power bi and the dax. Can you give a hint please.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @user5226582. It worked.
I did it by mentioning Top 3 in visual level filters

Comment: I didn't do much, but glad you got it sorted!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i got the solution.
I did mentioned in Top N filtering of visual level filter of fields.
[image]

And it worked for me.

Thanks for the hint @user5226582

Comment: looks great! Make sure to mark this as the answer :)